# LALR construction from recursive grammar

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, recursion, lalr

Suppose I've to parse a list of one and unique terminal token x.

I might be wrong but I thing I've two way:

- One declaring a recursive non terminal this way : A -> xA
- One other declaring a recursive non terminal that way : A -> Ax

That should leaves me with these two DFA of Item sets (if I'm not wrong once again) :

[image: DFA]

That shows me that only the first way produces recursivity.

At this point I'm sure to be wrong in my method to construct DFA from grammar.
Could you so explain me what did I do wrong?
I if your motivation is strong enough, could you give and explain method to achieve LALR table construction with both grammar? (Including First() and Follow() finding).

I can read some C code easily if you want to answer with some pseudo code.
I come from [this](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~sjackson/lalr1.html) site to try to understand LALR table construction.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: before to understand LALR you must well understand LR and LL.  LALR is a little optimization made to LR using First and Follow  operators.  You can use the textbook https://www.amazon.fr/Parsing-Techniques-Practical-Monographs-Computer/dp/1441919015 of Grune.  First 9 chapters.  This book is really well written for beginners.

Comment: Yes, we could say that the problem I expose is an LR table construction problem at the first place. This question spawned in my head because I was trying LR table construction. I had an issue, and I expose it...

Comment: The book you point is a little expensive to me and there is another problem, I'm french, so I sometimes need lots of different way explaining the same thing to make me understand some concepts in english.

Comment: la premiere edition est gratuite et il vaut la peine de le lire. la voici https://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/BookBody.pdf  -- de plus, je vous sugere egalement prendre un cours d'automates avant, car l'analyse de texte est en fait une application des automates finis pour les expression regulieres et des automates au pile pour les langages plus complexes, comme C, java, etc.

Comment: Haaaa, ça ça vas m'aider, merci beaucoup. Après le savoir sur les automates c'est pas trop un problème, j'ai déjà mon analyseur lexical maison, je sait fabriquer des NFA et DFA à partir d'expressions régulières. C'est la transformation d'une grammaire en table LR puis LALR qui me pose plus problème. Mais je vais potasser votre lien, et peut-être répondrais-je moi même à ma question.

Comment: If the french book has a dragon (and a knight) on the cover I can warmly recommend it. I read the German version. The contents was as good as the translation into German.

Comment: @Scheff for parsing the book of Grune is the best, Ullman's book is not so detailed on parsers as Grune's

Comment: @LewisAnesa oui, le LR est bel et bien le mieux explique dans le livre de Grune.

Comment: Scheff ne fait-il pas référence au dragon book? J'y ai jetté un coup d'oeuil déjà, mais je ne l'ai pas trouvé en français. alinsoar, seriez-vous capable de sortir les tables LR des deux grammaires que j'ai proposées? Peut-être sont-elle trop ambiguës pour entrer dans le cadre de ce genre d'exercice...

Comment: In fact, it seems that I'm on the right way : The first grammar wiil stack every x and can redious last x to A but I don't know how to trigger this reductions at the end of the list and only at this moment? The second grammar will reduce the first x to A and all following x by A->Ax rule but once again, how to trigger the N->A reduction at the end of the list and only at this moment? That's why I talk about the look ahead token.

Comment: What are the functions of `S` and `N` here? If you intens `S` to be the "augmented" starting symbol, the production should be `S->N $` where `$` is the end-of-input marker. Adding `$` might make the parse process clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I've reduce/reduce conflict in my LR(0) method. Looks like LR(1) resolves it but hugely increase table size. That's why I search some answers on LALR method. Note : I'm still learning.